# xero-php-oauth2 - Search feature pulling in ALL records

Tags: php, oauth, xero-api

Firstly thank you for your support in advance and i am sorry if im being stupid i have been working on this all night without avail.

Im making a wordpress plugin to connect Xero accounts with PMPro (Paid membership pro WP) but it seems i cannot filter out a single xero contact.

I am trying to search for a contact in xero using the API and users email address but my code below simply shows ALL users accounts and no matter what the email address "search string" is it still pulls in ALL accounts :/

```
$storage = new StorageClass();
$xeroTenantId = (string)$storage->getSession()->tenant_id;
 
$config = XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken( (string)$storage->getSession()->token );      

$apiInstance = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
);
$searchTerm="searchTerm=ben.bowden@24locks.com";

try {
  $result = $apiInstance->getContacts($xeroTenantId, $searchTerm);
  print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Exception when calling AccountingApi->getContacts: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
        
    }
```

Can anyone point out what im doing wrong....

Answer (score 1):

It seems you dont need "SearchTerm=" in your query as the API class converts it to a querystring so instead of

$searchTerm = "searchTerm=some@email.com";

You would use

$searchTerm = "some@email.com";